# Supertest POST request hangs

Tags: jestjs, nest, supertest

I am running `supertest` on `Jest` and trying to test a simple `POST` request:

```
test('A simple POST', done => {
    const appHttpServer = app.getHttpServer();
    const _request = request(appHttpServer);

    return _request
      .post(`my-post-url`)
      .type('json')
      .send(someData)

      .expect(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED, done);
  });
```

The test passes as expected, however it stays hang. Running with `--detectOpenHandles` results with: 
`Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.`

If I try a non-post request, everything works as expected and the test exits correctly.

What am I doing wrong in this case?